# Jersy 2 Client + JAXB (MessageBodyWriter not found)

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey

I'm trying to use Jersy 2 in client mode to post XML to a server but i always get an exception.

I have got only one dependency in my pom file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
    <version>2.18</version>
</dependency>
```

My Java code:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    Client client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    WebTarget target = client.target("http://localhost:8080");
    Entity<SimpleClass> entity = Entity.entity(new SimpleClass(), MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE);
    target.request(MediaType.TEXT_XML_TYPE).post(entity);
}

@XmlRootElement(name = "test")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
public class SimpleClass {
    @XmlElement(name = "hello")
    private String text;

    public String getText() {
        return text;
    }

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}
```

Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class jersey.SimpleClass, genericType=class jersey.SimpleClass.
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Jersey version issue: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/xml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754641/jersey-version-issue-messagebodyreader-not-found-for-media-type-application-xml)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thank's to peeskillet!

Since Jersey 2.16 you have to add JAX-B support:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
    <version>2.18</version>
</dependency>
```

See:
[Jersey version issue: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754641/jersey-version-issue-messagebodyreader-not-found-for-media-type-application-xml)