# Jersey messagebodywriter not found for xml

Tags: java, jersey

I make a request:
`Response response = target.request(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).post(Entity.xml(inputData));`

This generates an error:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml
```

From other answers here I have gathered that it might be a dependency issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30820037/3592255

I already have this dependency though:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>2.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        <version>2.18</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        <version>2.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.18</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-media-jaxb</artifactId>
        <version>2.18</version>
    </dependency>
```

Any input would be appreciated

Comment: Do you have `@XmlRootElement` on the model class?

Comment: Actually no, it has been generetad with XJC and it seems only some of the generated classes have @XmlRootElement. Is there any way to force XJC to add it to all classes?

Comment: I don't know. Maybe ask another question tagged with jaxb and xjc. Or google it see if you can find something first.