# Getting error SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml,

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, jax-ws

Jersey `GET/POST` call throws following error after upgrading jaxrs and jaxws jar to latest version in my project:

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor aroundWriteTo
SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/xml, type=class java.util.ArrayList, genericType=java.util.List<javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement<com.play.ClassBase>
```

It is working fine for `Accept:application/json`, but for `application/xml`.I am getting error.How to fix it?

Comment: The problem can be because of lack of conversion code which knows how to automatically convert your response into XML. Could you share your JSON Request-Response? Also, which Library are you using for XML Conversion?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30754994/2587435)

Answer (score 1):

Please, verify that you have the jersey-media-jaxb.jar in your lib folder of your application.