# REST Service client application in JAVA

Tags: java, mysql, rest, web

```
  CreateEmployeeJerseyClient client1=new CreateEmployeeJerseyClient();
  ClientResponse response=client1.findAll_XML(ClientResponse.class);

  GenericType<List<TblEmployee>> genericType = new GenericType<List<TblEmployee>>() {};
  List<TblEmployee> data= new ArrayList<TblEmployee>();
  data=(response.getEntity(genericType));
  Employee p=new Employee();
  p.setId(5);
  p.setFirstname("Johan");
  p.setLastname("Russel");
  p.setGender("Male");
  p.setAddress("sss");
  client1.create_XML(p);
```

When I implement this code in Java (JDK 1.8) to save data in MYSQL, it showing the error like "Method getEntity() in class ClientResponse cannot be applied to given types"

I referred these below links.
https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/RESTfulWebServices_Part2/RESTfulWebservicesPart2.htm
https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/RESTfulWebServices/RESTfulWebservices.htm

Comment: The links you're referring to use Jersey 1.x while you're probably using Jersey 2.x or even Jersey 3.x. From Jersey 2.x on, there's no method getEntity() which could be applied to an instance of GenericType. You'll want to use [readEntity()](https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jersey.github.io/apidocs/2.22/jersey/javax/ws/rs/core/Response.html#readEntity(javax.ws.rs.core.GenericType)) instead.

Comment: When I use readentity() method, it is showing error like Exception in thread "main" org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyReader not found for media type=application/xml, type=class org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse, genericType=class org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientResponse.
 at org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$TerminalReaderInterceptor.aroundReadFrom(ReaderInterceptorExecutor.java:207).

Comment: So, the compilation error is gone, that is your first problem is solved. Now, you're faced with a runtime error which is a different story. Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30754641/jersey-version-issue-messagebodyreader-not-found-for-media-type-application-xml